# Extracting Minute Stock Data in C#

Tags: c#

Using the function below, I am trying to download minute stock data for "Googl". Using the code below that I am loading the data into c# and then exporting it into a csv is coming out Daily and I want the data to be intra-day. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
public OHLCQuoteCollection GetHistoricalPrices(string symbol, DateTime StartDate = new DateTime(), DateTime EndDate = new DateTime())
{
    var url = ServiceURL + "PriceHistory?source=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(AppKey) + "&requestidentifiertype=SYMBOL&requestvalue=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(symbol) +
        "&intervaltype=DAILY&intervalduration=1&startdate=" + StartDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "&enddate=" + EndDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

    return InvokeWebRequest<OHLCQuoteCollection>(url);
}



namespace TDAmeritrade.Samples
{
    using System;
    using TDAmeritrade;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System.IO;

    class Program
    {

        static void Main()
        {
            // Initialize TD Ameritrade client, provide additional config info if needed
            var client = new TDAClient();

            // Log in to the TD Ameritrade website with your user ID and password
            client.LogIn("jessiausername", "jessicapassword");

            // Now 'client.User' property contains all the information about currently logged in user
            var accountName = client.User.Account.DisplayName;

            // Get stock quotes snapshot.
            var quotes = client.GetQuotes("GOOG, AAPL, $SPX.X, DUMMY");

            // 'quotes.Error' contains a list of symbols which have not been found
            var errors = quotes.Errors;

            // Find symbols matching the search string
            var symbols = client.FindSymbols("GOO");

            // Get historical prices
            var prices = client.GetHistoricalPrices("GOOG, AAPL", StartDate: DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7), EndDate: DateTime.Today.AddDays);

            //Print output of "prices" into a csv file

            const string SaveFileToLocation = @"C:\Users\JessicaAnnStrada\Desktop\json_data\myfile.csv";
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(prices, Formatting.Indented);
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(SaveFileToLocation))
            {
                writer.Write(json);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's in your `url` string:

> intervaltype=DAILY

Change this to whatever you need.

Comment: Hey dymanoid! So does anything in the "prices" variable also have any influence on the frequency of the data, namley this part "StartDate: DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7), EndDate: DateTime.Today.AddDays". Does changing any of that part change the frequency or is it just the URL?

Comment: I suppose you need to better understand how that web request and json stuff works. You send a web request as an url to the server, and the server responds you providing the requested data. So this data depends on what you request via the url string. So the url is the key - it contains the "command" to the server: "I need exactly this". You should build your url string carefully to specify the server what data do you need.